# Codeigniter maximal controller length

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there any maximal length of controller class in codeigniter?
for me one controller wasn't working but when i deleted some lines the same code started working . anyone know whats going on ?

working code :

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH')) {
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
}

class C_Object_details extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        respoti_profiler();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->model('m_object_details');
        $this->params['set_tag'] = array();
        $this->params['title_auto'] = true;
    }
    protected function convert_meta_results($result_meta) {
        $meta_list = array();
        foreach ($result_meta as $value) {
            $meta_list[$value['meta_key']] = $value['meta_value'];
        }
        return $meta_list;
    }

    public function index() {
        $id = (int) $this->uri->segment(2);

        $object = $this->m_object_details->get_object($id);

        if (empty($object)) {
            show_404(sprintf('Brak obiektu o id: %s', $id));
        }
        $result_meta = $this->m_object_details->get_object_meta($id);
        $meta_list = $this->convert_meta_results($result_meta);
        unset($result_meta);

        $rooms = array();
        if ($object['post_url'] === 'hotel') {
            $room_list = $this->m_object_details->get_room_list($object['post_code']);

            foreach ($room_list as $key => $val) {
                $where_in[] = $val['room_id'];
            }

            /* pobranie danych meta pokoi */
            $room_meta_list = $this->m_object_details->get_room_meta($where_in);

            foreach ($room_meta_list as $key => $value) {
                $rooms[$value['metaroom_room_id']]['meta'][$value['metaroom_key']] = $value['metaroom_value'];
            }

            foreach ($room_list as $key => $val) {
                $rooms[$val['room_id']]['room'] = $val;
            }

            unset($room_list, $room_meta_list);
        }

        //wygenerowanie listy atrybutow pokoi
        $rooms_pref = array();
        foreach ($rooms as $value) {
            if (isset($value['meta'])) {
                foreach ($value['meta'] as $key1 => $value) {
                    if (strpos($key, 'pref-') === false) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $rooms_pref[$key1] = $value;
                }
            }
        }

        ## OPINIE ##
        $count = 0;
        $opinia = 0;

        $arr_opinion = array();

        if (isset($meta_list['obj_booking_opinion'])) {
            $arr_opinion[] = $meta_list['obj_booking_opinion'];
        }

        if (isset($meta_list['obj_google_opinion'])) {
            $arr_opinion[] = $meta_list['obj_google_opinion'];
        }

        if (isset($meta_list['obj_hrs_opinion'])) {
            $arr_opinion[] = $meta_list['obj_hrs_opinion'];
        }

        if (isset($meta_list['obj_ta_opinion'])) {
            $arr_opinion[] = $meta_list['obj_ta_opinion'];
        }

        foreach ($arr_opinion as $value) {
            $tmp_value = 0 + ( str_replace(',', '.', $value) );
            if ($tmp_value > 0) {
                $count++;
                $opinia += $tmp_value;
            }
        }

        if ($count === 0) {
            $opinia = 0;
        } else {
            $opinia = round($opinia / $count, 1);
        }

        if ($opinia < 10) {
            $opinia = number_format($opinia, 1, '.', '');
        }


        $arr_opinioncount = array();
        if (isset($meta_list['obj_booking_opinioncount'])) {
            $arr_opinioncount[] = $meta_list['obj_booking_opinioncount'];
        }

        if (isset($meta_list['obj_hrs_opinioncount'])) {
            $arr_opinioncount[] = $meta_list['obj_hrs_opinioncount'];
        }

        if (isset($meta_list['obj_google_opinioncount'])) {
            $arr_opinioncount[] = $meta_list['obj_google_opinioncount'];
        }

        if (isset($meta_list['obj_ta_opinioncount'])) {
            $arr_opinioncount[] = $meta_list['obj_ta_opinioncount'];
        }

        $ilosc_opini = 0;
        foreach ($arr_opinioncount as $value) {
            $ilosc_opini += $value;
        }


        ## KONIEC OPINI ##
        ## LINKI DO GALERI ##
        $link_thumb = 'http://exifex.pl/system/uploads/300/';
        $link_full = 'http://exifex.pl/system/uploads/';

        $gallery_thumb = glob(sprintf("/home/respoti/domains/exifex.pl/public_html/system/uploads/300/%s*", $object['post_code']));
        $gallery_full = glob(sprintf("/home/respoti/domains/exifex.pl/public_html/system/uploads/%s*", $object['post_code']));
        ## KONIEC LINKI DO GALERII ##
        ## hotele wyciag 



        if (isset($meta_list['attraction_price'])) {
            $atr_price = $meta_list['attraction_price'];
        } else
            $atr_price = null;
        if (isset($meta_list['rest_pricerange'])) {
            $rest_price_range = $meta_list['rest_pricerange'];
        } else {
            $rest_price_range = null;
        }


//dodane dzis
        if (isset($meta_list['attraction_eventsorganized'])) {
            $attr_type = $meta_list['attraction_eventsorganized'];
        } else {
            $attr_type = null;
        }

        if (isset($meta_list['rest_openhoursrange_start'])) {
            $pn_pt = $meta_list['rest_openhoursrange_start'];
        } else {
            $pn_pt = null;
        }
        if (isset($meta_list['rest_openhoursrange_end'])) {
            $pn_pt_e = $meta_list['rest_openhoursrange_end'];
        } else {
            $pn_pt_e = null;
        }

        if (isset($meta_list['rest_openhoursweekend_start'])) {
            $pt = $meta_list['rest_openhoursweekend_start'];
        } else {
            $pt = null;
        }
        if (isset($meta_list['rest_openhoursweekend_end'])) {
            $pt_e = $meta_list['rest_openhoursweekend_end'];
        } else {
            $pt_e = null;
        }

        if (isset($meta_list['rest_openhourssunday_start'])) {
            $sun = $meta_list['rest_openhourssunday_start'];
        } else {
            $sun = null;
        }
        if (isset($meta_list['rest_openhourssunday_end'])) {
            $sun_e = $meta_list['rest_openhourssunday_end'];
        } else {
            $sun_e = null;
        }


        if (isset($meta_list['nightlife_openhourssunday_start'])) {
            $n_sun = $meta_list['nightlife_openhourssunday_start'];
        } else {
            $n_sun = null;
        }
        if (isset($meta_list['nightlife_openhourssunday_end'])) {
            $n_sun_e = $meta_list['nightlife_openhourssunday_end'];
        } else {
            $n_sun_e = null;
        }

        if (isset($meta_list['nightlife_openhoursweekend_start'])) {
            $n_pt = $meta_list['nightlife_openhoursweekend_start'];
        } else {
            $n_pt = null;
        }
        if (isset($meta_list['nightlife_openhoursweekend_end'])) {
            $n_pt_e = $meta_list['nightlife_openhoursweekend_end'];
        } else {
            $n_pt_e = null;
        }

        if (isset($meta_list['nightlife_openhoursrange_start'])) {
            $n_pn_pt = $meta_list['nightlife_openhoursrange_start'];
        } else {
            $n_pn_pt = null;
        }
        if (isset($meta_list['nightlife_openhoursrange_end'])) {
            $n_pn_pt_e = $meta_list['nightlife_openhoursrange_end'];
        } else {
            $n_pn_pt_e = null;
        }

        if (isset($meta_list['nightlife_open_1_start'])) {
            $pn_1 = $meta_list['nightlife_open_1_start'];
        } else
            $pn_1 = null;
        if (isset($meta_list['nightlife_open_1_end'])) {
            $pn_2 = $meta_list['nightlife_open_1_end'];
        } else
            $pn_2 = null;
        if (isset($meta_list['nightlife_open_2_start'])) {
            $wt_1 = $meta_list['nightlife_open_2_start'];
        } else
            $wt_1 = null;
        if (isset($meta_list['nightlife_open_2_end'])) {
            $wt_2 = $meta_list['nightlife_open_2_end'];
        } else
            $wt_2 = null;
        if (isset($meta_list['nightlife_open_3_start'])) {
            $sr_1 = $meta_list['nightlife_open_3_start'];
        } else
            $sr_1 = null;
        if (isset($meta_list['nightlife_open_3_end'])) {
            $sr_2 = $meta_list['nightlife_open_3_end'];
        } else
            $sr_2 = null;

        if (isset($meta_list['nightlife_open_4_start'])) {
            $czw_1 = $meta_list['nightlife_open_4_start'];
        } else
            $czw_1 = null;
        if (isset($meta_list['nightlife_open_4_end'])) {
            $czw_2 = $meta_list['nightlife_open_4_end'];
        } else
            $czw_2 = null;

        if (isset($meta_list['nightlife_open_5_start'])) {
            $pt_1 = $meta_list['nightlife_open_5_start'];
        } else
            $pt_1 = null;
        if (isset($meta_list['nightlife_open_5_end'])) {
            $pt_2 = $meta_list['nightlife_open_5_end'];
        } else
            $pt_2 = null;


        if (isset($meta_list['nightlife_open_6_start'])) {
            $sob_1 = $meta_list['nightlife_open_6_start'];
        } else
            $sob_1 = null;
        if (isset($meta_list['nightlife_open_6_end'])) {
            $sob_2 = $meta_list['nightlife_open_6_end'];
        } else
            $sob_2 = null;


        if (isset($meta_list['nightlife_open_7_start'])) {
            $nd_1 = $meta_list['nightlife_open_7_start'];
        } else
            $nd_1 = null;
        if (isset($meta_list['nightlife_open_7_end'])) {
            $nd_2 = $meta_list['nightlife_open_7_end'];
        } else
            $nd_2 = null;


//rest
        if (isset($meta_list['rest_open_1_start'])) {
            $r_pn_1 = $meta_list['rest_open_1_start'];
        } else
            $r_pn_1 = null;
        if (isset($meta_list['rest_open_1_end'])) {
            $r_pn_2 = $meta_list['rest_open_1_end'];
        } else
            $r_pn_2 = null;

        if (isset($meta_list['rest_open_2_start'])) {
            $r_wt_1 = $meta_list['rest_open_2_start'];
        } else
            $r_wt_1 = null;
        if (isset($meta_list['rest_open_2_end'])) {
            $r_wt_2 = $meta_list['rest_open_2_end'];
        } else
            $r_wt_2 = null;

        if (isset($meta_list['rest_open_3_start'])) {
            $r_sr_1 = $meta_list['rest_open_3_start'];
        } else
            $r_sr_1 = null;
        if (isset($meta_list['rest_open_3_end'])) {
            $r_sr_2 = $meta_list['rest_open_3_end'];
        } else
            $r_sr_2 = null;
        if (isset($meta_list['rest_open_4_start'])) {
            $r_czw_1 = $meta_list['rest_open_4_start'];
        } else
            $r_czw_1 = null;
        if (isset($meta_list['rest_open_4_end'])) {
            $r_czw_2 = $meta_list['rest_open_4_end'];
        } else $r_czw_2 = null;

        if (isset($meta_list['rest_open_5_start'])) {
            $r_pt_1 = $meta_list['rest_open_5_start'];
        } else $r_pt_1 = null;
        if (isset($meta_list['rest_open_5_end'])) {
            $r_pt_2 = $meta_list['rest_open_5_end'];
        } else
            $r_pt_2 = null;

        if (isset($meta_list['rest_open_6_start'])) {
            $r_sob_1 = $meta_list['rest_open_6_start'];
        } else
            $r_sob_1 = null;
        if (isset($meta_list['rest_open_6_end'])) {
            $r_sob_2 = $meta_list['rest_open_6_end'];
        } else
            $r_sob_2 = null;


        if (isset($meta_list['rest_open_7_start'])) {
            $r_nd_1 = $meta_list['rest_open_7_start'];
        } else
            $r_nd_1 = null;
        if (isset($meta_list['rest_open_7_end'])) {
            $r_nd_2 = $meta_list['rest_open_7_end'];
        } else
            $r_nd_2 = null;
        $params = array(
            'object' => $object,'meta' => $meta_list,'rooms' => $rooms,
            'rooms_pref' => $rooms_pref,'opinia' => $opinia,'opinia_opisowa' => config('opinia_opisowa'),
            'ilosc_opini' => $ilosc_opini,
            'link_thumb' => $link_thumb,
            'link_full' => $link_full,
            'gallery_thumb' => $gallery_thumb,
            'gallery_full' => $gallery_full,
            'title' => $object['post_title'],
            'email' => $meta_list['email_object'],
            'web' => $meta_list['obj_site'],
            'phone' => $meta_list['obj_phone'],
            'typ' => $object['post_url'], 
            'adres' => $object['post_address'],
            'post_code' => $object['post_post'],
            'fb' => $meta_list['obj_fb'],
            'pref' => $this->m_object_details->get_pref($id),
            'typ_hot' => $object['post_object_type'],
            'kuchnia' => $this->m_object_details->get_kitchen($id),
            'rcena' => $rest_price_range,
            'acena' => $atr_price,
            'typ_obj' => $this->m_object_details->get_smth($id, 'attraction_eventsorganized'),
            'pn_pt' => $pn_pt,'pn_pt_e' => $pn_pt_e,'pt' => $pt,'pt_e' => $pt_e,'sun' => $sun,
            'sun_e' => $sun_e,'n_pn_pt' => $n_pn_pt,
            'n_pn_pt_e' => $n_pn_pt_e,'n_pt' => $n_pt,
            'n_pt_e' => $n_pt_e,'n_sun' => $n_sun,'n_sun_e' => $n_sun_e,
            'attr_type' => $attr_type,'pn_1' => $pn_1,'pn_2' => $pn_2,
            'wt_1' => $wt_1,'wt_2' => $wt_2,'sr_1' => $sr_1,'sr_2' => $sr_2,
            'czw_1' => $czw_1,'czw_2' => $czw_2,'pt_1' => $pt_1, 'pt_2' => $pt_2,
            'sob_1' => $sob_1,'sob_2' => $sob_2,
            'nd_1' => $nd_1,'nd_2' => $nd_2,'r_pn_1' => $r_pn_1,'r_pn_2' => $r_pn_2,'r_wt_1' => $r_wt_1,
            'r_wt_2' => $r_wt_2,'r_sr_1' => $r_sr_1,'r_sr_2' => $r_sr_2,
            'r_czw_1' => $r_czw_1,'r_czw_2' => $r_czw_2,
            'r_pt_1' => $r_pt_1,'r_pt_2' => $r_pt_2,'r_sob_1' => $r_sob_1,
            'r_sob_2' => $r_sob_2,'r_nd_1' => $r_nd_1,'r_nd_2' => $r_nd_2
        );

        $hotel_data = array(
            'hotel_adres' => $object['post_address'],
            'hotel_email' => $meta_list['email_object'],
            'hotel_telefon' => $meta_list['obj_phone'],
            'hotel_post_code' => $object['post_post'],
            'hotel_gps_lat' => $meta_list['lat'],
            'hotel_gps_lng' => $meta_list['lng'],
            'hotel_name' => $object['post_title'],
        );
        //$this->session->set_userdata('hotel_adres',$adres);
        $this->session->set_userdata($hotel_data);
        $this->params = array_merge($this->params, $params);
        $this->load->view('object_details/index', $this->params);
    }

}
```

not working was added this :

```
$email = $meta_list['email_object'];
        $web = $meta_list['obj_site'];
        $telefon = $meta_list['obj_phone'];
        $adres = $object['post_address'];
        $post_code = $object['post_post'];
        $typ = $object['post_url'];
        $typ_hot = $object['post_object_type'];
        $fb = $meta_list['obj_fb'];
        $moc = $this->m_object_details->get_all_meta_key();
        $kuchnia = $this->m_object_details->get_kitchen($id);


     body is limited to 30 k chars ::<
```

Comment: Indicate what is the error you were getting, and post the code of your controller. It is not about the lenght, but mostly probable an issue with the code itself you have removed.

Comment: it was not displaying anything. there were no errors or other. i deleted some   lines that was not making anything

Comment: what is your classname? Also include your working and non working codes.

Comment: Blank page does not always mean no errors. Enable error reporting and error reporting like so, and post the code snippet to clarify. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigntier does not have any rule for class/function code length.Its same as PHP.

As I know PHP does not have any limitation for clasname or function length.So CI does not have any limitation.

But Its hard to debug your such long code where you made mistake.

Comment: there is no mistakes. on other server it works as well. and i still dont know why on main server it crashes

Comment: There must be mistakes/errors.Check php version may be you have some code which has version dependency.if you see blank page means you get some errors check your error log what you got.